# Getting 11205 error when trying to use calls().update to transfer to conference room

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, twilio

I'm trying to move the inbound caller to a conference room:

```
//this is the endpoint for the voice webhook
app.post('/voice',(req,res)=>{
    sid=req.body.CallSid;
    conferenceName="test conference room";
    params={'conferenceName':conferenceName};
    url='https://appname.herokuapp.com/addToConference?conferenceName=test';
    console.log('now updating inbound call sid '+sid);
    client.calls(sid).update({
        url:url,
        method:'GET'
    });

});

//this is the endpoint for adding a caller to a conference
app.get('/addToConference',(req,res)=>{
    var conferenceName=req.query.conferenceName;
    const response=new VoiceResponse();
    response.say("Now connecting you to conference "+conferenceName);
    dial=response.dial();
    dial.conference(conferenceName);
    responseTwiml=response.toString();
    console.log("responseTwiml: "+responseTwiml);
    res.send(responseTwiml);
});
```

Console logging shows that the `.update()` call is reached:

```
now updating inbound call sid 9j92f892309
```

But then the Twilio debugger shows an 11205 error, where the url is `https://appname.herokuapp.com/voice/`.  The console log does not show `Now connecting you to conference test`, so I'm guessing the `/addToConference` endpoint isn't being reached.  Heroku error log shows a `Request timeout` error.

How can I reach the endpoint and drop the inbound caller into a conference call?  If it matters, I want the app to then call someone else, interact with them, and then transfer that call recipient to the conference where the inbound caller is waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's a couple of issues here. To start with, the [11205 error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11205) is because of a timeout from the call to your `/voice` endpoint. The issue here is that you never return anything from the function with the `res`. You could fix that one by calling `res.send('')` at the end of that function.

However...

There is no need to do the redirect that you're doing at all. You can use the initial webhook response to both drop the caller into the conference and dial the other party. You would do this with the following code:

```
app.post('/voice',(req,res)=>{
    conferenceName="test conference room";
    url='https://appname.herokuapp.com/addToConference?conferenceName=' + conferenceName;
    client.calls.create({
        from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
        to: THE_OTHER_PERSON,
        url: url
    });
    const response=new VoiceResponse();
    response.say("Now connecting you to conference "+conferenceName);
    dial=response.dial();
    dial.conference(conferenceName);
    responseTwiml=response.toString();
    res.set('Content-Type': 'text/xml');
    res.send(responseTwiml);
});
```

For this you will still need the `/addToConference` endpoint which just adds the other caller to the conference, which would look like this:

```
app.get('/addToConference',(req,res)=>{
    var conferenceName=req.query.conferenceName;
    const response=new VoiceResponse();
    response.say("Now connecting you to conference "+conferenceName);
    dial=response.dial();
    dial.conference(conferenceName);
    responseTwiml=response.toString();
    console.log("responseTwiml: "+responseTwiml);
    res.send(responseTwiml);
});
```

You could also redirect the caller in the way you wanted to do in the first place, but instead of [modifying the call with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls) you would use the [TwiML `<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) verb. That would look like this:

```
app.post('/voice',(req,res)=>{
    conferenceName="test conference room";
    url='https://appname.herokuapp.com/addToConference?conferenceName=' + conferenceName;
    client.calls.create({
        from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
        to: THE_OTHER_PERSON,
        url: url
    });
    const response=new VoiceResponse();
    response.redirect(url);
    responseTwiml=response.toString();
    res.set('Content-Type': 'text/xml');
    res.send(responseTwiml);
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.